# Настройка соединения по сети

Tags: виртуализация, vpn, virtualbox, vmware, linux

Здраствуйте уважаемые!

Назрел такой вопрос - честно не знаю даже как задать ибо по таким темам я полный ноль.

Итак - есть машина - с 7-кой на борту - со статическим ип (т.е. доступ "к" и "из" сети) - на машине крутятся пара виртуальных машин - образы [TurnKey](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/) Linux - БД сервер PostGreSQL и SVN хостинг. С хоста до виртуалках и обратно доступ есть, но хотелось бы получить доступ и к виртуалкам из сети. Т.е. - допустим с рабочего компа, который вообще во внутренней корпоративной сети, достучаться до БД сервера или SVN репозитория.

Что посоветуете? В какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё зависит от сетевой инфраструктуры.

Если есть [L2](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C) доступ к локальной сети, то нужно настроить гостевые сетевухи в режиме bridge вместо nat, назначить им ip-адреса из этой сети, доступ будет получен по этим адресам.

Если нет и под "статическим ип" имелось ввиду статический "белый" ip в Интернете, то нужно сделать портфорвард навскидку [для vmware](http://nileshk.com/2009/06/24/vmware-fusion-nat-dhcp-and-port-forwarding.html) и [для virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) это делается так.

Думаю, что всё ))

Comment: вот неплохая статья в тему http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/vm/VirtualBox-networking.html